# Wrong JSON output with bidirectional Jackson Infinite Recursion Solution

Tags: json, hibernate

As explained in [baeldung blog](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion), I have use @JsonIdentityInfo solutio to solve issue (bidirectional Jackson Infinite Recursion)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Payment")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "uuid")
public class Payment implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "registration", nullable = false)
    private Registration registration;
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Registration")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uuid")
public class Registration implements Serializable {
    ...
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="registration", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Payment> payment;
    ...
}
```

It works, I didn't have recursion error but the JSON output is wrong :

[image: Brower Console Output]

What is wrong please ?

Comment: This really doesn't tell us anything, because we can't know how that output is "wrong" for you, but have you tried using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to avoid recursions? They work well when deserializing, but `@JsonBackReference` works as `@JsonIgnore` when serializing.

Comment: This is wrong because output is not only object list. I think that recursive items are replaced by object's uuid. I don't need avoid recusions but just limit it